# Using Yeoman with a remote server

Tags: workflow, gruntjs, yeoman

I've just read about [Yeoman](http://yeoman.io) (and all around) and liked the concept. But instead of other frontend developers I use a remote server for developing on my machine. Different projects need different PHP installations, settings, etc.

So I assume a can't use Yeoman as it is, right?

My thoughts are:
Install Yeoman on my local machine, bootstrap new applications with yo and use bower for packages. On the remote server, install grunt and watch the uploaded files to do tasks like compile scss, inject the new css / reload the page, ...

Is this the correct way or is there something that I'm missing?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I have done something similar, and for simplicity's sake:

- installed yeoman on the remote server
- edited the Gruntfile.js grunt.initConfig -> connect -> options to appropriate settings (0.0.0.0:80)
- commented out the open task that is included in the serve task, this prevents `grunt serve` from attempting open the URL and fails on *nix machines without X.

This is great because it still works with the LiveReload functionality. Gotta <3 Yeoman.